# Configure Cygwin to NOT use FTP for updates

Tags: ftp, cygwin, setup

In an attempt to progressively replace Windows servers with Linux boxes, I am looking for a unified way of administering a mixed network of the two. The current in-house daemon that we use for the Windows admin accepts commands in a similar syntax to Unix: ls, cp, ... so my idea was to try and do all the admin per ssh.

I can install Cygwin on Windows and install a local sshd too. I have found the apt-cyg script, to install stuff similar to apt-get in Debian/Ubuntu.

Now my problem is that it seems lots of update sites in Cygwin are FTP sites, which are all blocked by our firewall. Unfortunately they don't fail immediately, but just time-out. I am assuming there is for every such site an HTTP equivalent site.

Is there a way to globally tell the Cygwin setup, which is used by apt-cyg, to NOT use any FTP sites? Preferably without me having to go through all the files and deleting them manually?

Comment: Cygwin's installer only uses the sites that you tell it to use either in the GUI or on the command line. The mirror list just gives you a choice, so it's not clear why you're concerned about ftp sites appearing there.

Comment: I can just call "apt-cyg update". I do not get asked anything, and it uses some default update sites and they all fail because for some reason it prefers FTP sites.

Answer (score 0):

That is not directly an answer to the question, but at least a possible work-around.

Firstly, there is an apt-get.sh in Cygwin, so you don't need to find and install apt-cyg.

Secondly, Cygwin saves the mirrors you used in:

```
C:\cygwin\setup
```

so make sure to delete and ftp mirrors there, and then call:

```
apt-get.sh -m THE_MIRROR_OF_YOUR_CHOICE update
```

Then, it will save info about that mirror in C:\cygwin\setup, and it seems it will use it by default, so that you don't have to specify it explicitly anymore. Problem solved, as long as that one mirror does not go down.